# CSS naming convention - nested CSS

Tags: html, css

This is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/PduBG/7/

My question is from a CSS point of view, is it wrong to be doing this:

```
.header {
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 20px
}
.header ul {
    float: right;
}
.header ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Instead, would something like this be better:

```
.header {
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 20px
}
#header_list {
    float: right;
}
#header_listitem {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: There could be hundreds of answers to this.  I like the first one, clear, no additional classes, but there are going to be a lot of opinions.

Comment: Both are valid. What is better in your situation is not something we can answer, however, whenever you can, it's probably best to avoid adding additional IDs to your markup if you don't need to. So I'd default to the first rather than the last as my preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real right or wrong here.

Technically the second option is faster to render because the browser just needs to scan for ID's instead of checking the nesting of elements, but in practice it won't be noticeable unless you have an enormous document.

To determine the best way, you need to check your semantics:

Do you want to style all your listitems that are in a header? Choose the first method

Do you want to style that specific item? Choose the second method

Answer (score 1):

U can do this
name your header -----> .header
name your ul ---->#header_list

```
.header {
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 20px
}
#header_list {
    float: right;
}
#header_list li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your scenario. If you use Id selector, this gets applied to all controls with this id. If you use class selector, it gives you the flexibility to set the style selectively on several elements.